# Is it possible to define new variable in view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is it possible to define new variable in view?
I have code like this. But I get the error `undefined local variable or method "who"`

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>

    <tr id="<%= dom_post_id(post) %>">

        <% if post.user.id == who %>
            <td><%= post.user.nickname if post.user %></td>
            <td><div class="bubble me"><%= post.body %></div></td>
            <td></td>
        <% else %>
            <td></td>
            <td><div class="bubble you"><%= post.body %></div></td>
            <td><%= post.user.nickname if post.user %></td>     
        <% end %>
    </tr>
    <% who = post.user.id %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible, but just as regular ruby, you should assign it a value, before comparing something to it.

Here:

```
<% if post.user.id == who %>
```

`who` has not yet been seen anywhere so ruby doesn't know what this is.

Comment: Thanks this is perfect answer.  by the way, it doesn't work I wanted it to. Do you know why? It's supposed to be shown in different <td> if the user was different.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
<% if post.user.id == who %>
```

You haven't defined `who` yet. You define it later with `<% who = post.user.id %>`, but when the loop is first entered, `who` is not defined yet.

You'll need to define it before you use it.

Answer (score 1):

Move the who top before actually using it

```
<tr id="<%= dom_post_id(post) %>">
    <% who = post.user.id %>
    <% if post.user.id == who %>
        <td><%= post.user.nickname if post.user %></td>
        <td><div class="bubble me"><%= post.body %></div></td>
        <td></td>
    <% else %>
        <td></td>
        <td><div class="bubble you"><%= post.body %></div></td>
        <td><%= post.user.nickname if post.user %></td>     
    <% end %>
</tr>
```

HTH

Comment: Then it'll always judges it as the same person in you logic

Comment: Your error was not due to logic, but using an undefined variable. So my (as well as all the other answers) will resolve that. If you want to implement a logic ,then you should give more info about what you are trying to do